# jquery each doesnt increment

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

im trying to show a set of div's one by one by clicking a button. Im trying to do it with the jquery's each function but it just shows the first element, and if i click again it seems to try to show the same element again. Here's my code:

```
function showNewElement(buttonName) {
    switch (buttonName) {
        case "ingrediente":
            var elementNumber = 0;

            p(".newIngredient").each(function (elementNumber) {
                p(this, elementNumber).show();
                elementNumber++;
                return false;
            });

            break;

        case "paso":
            console.log("pasoAdicional");
            break;
    }

}
```

any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That code... simply doesn't make any sense. you aren't using .each correctly. You also aren't using `$(selector, context)` correctly, an integer can't be a context...

Comment: Returning false breaks the loop and stops iteration.

Comment: you don't need to declare elementNumber and no need to increment it, that will be index of the selected elements

Answer (score 0):

why not just do $('.newIngredient').show(); ? that will show all elements with the newIngredient class

Comment: i think what you need to do is use a global variable. scope the var outside of your function. then, every time that function is executed, increment it then. or, you could do something like $('.newIngedient:visible:last').next('.newIngedient').show();

Answer (score 0):

Why you are looping through `.newIngredient`. Just show() it using jQuery like:

```
case "ingrediente":
    var newIngredient = $('.newIngredient');
    // Count total number of ".newIngredient" element
    var elementNumber = newIngredient.length;
    // Make each element visible here
    newIngredient.show();
    break;
```